# Leaflet, animatedmarker over polyline array (JS)

Tags: javascript, animation, leaflet

Hoping some of you can help me out.

Using Gmaps encoded polyline arrays I've managed to create a map showing the polylines as a trip or journey. Now my intention is to use movingmarker.js to start at the beginning of the array, and end at the last GPS position.

However, after I've created an L.Polyline, the array has been sorted on duration instead of index.

```
$.each(response.currentTravel.legs, function(index) { 

        var polyline = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(response.currentTravel.legs[index].polyline);
        polyline.addTo(map);
        
        var latlng = polyline.getLatLngs();
        var duur = response.currentTravel.legs[index].duration
        var idline = parseInt(index)
                                            
        setTimeout(function() {             

        const arr = [idline,latlng,duur];

        for (const [idline, element] of arr.entries()) {
            console.log(`${idline}. ${element}`);
        };
                  
            animatedMarker = L.animatedMarker(latlng, {
                                    interval: duur*10, // milliseconds
                                    });
                    map.addLayer(animatedMarker);
                    
                }, duur*100);
            
            });
        });
                                                
};
```

When I console.log the polyline array out of the setTimeout function, the index remains as returned by Google, but when I'm doing the same in the for..of and setTimeout function, it returnes the order by the duration part of the array, instead of index. Data below:

```
currentTravel:
legs: Array(17)
0: {duration: 63, polyline: "_|r{H}myZ}@wFAQCM?O?G?E@E@CDE@AVUjAo@lAq@b@YNU"}
1: {duration: 107, polyline: "qvr{Hm}yZlBpFtB~FlBfFhA|C@Bh@vAbBrEFTd@pARh@Rl@@@@BLXJRLNHBHDf@HRB`@DdA\XXXXHPP\Rl@n@dB@FL\Lb@Lb@"}
2: {duration: 49, polyline: "kuq{H_cxZLZDTNYJQJQt@qAt@iAZq@BAVc@b@y@@AZm@DKDGHM^q@@AVYRQ@?JIPG@?NCLAN?RDD?@@D@^P"}
3: {duration: 194, polyline: "sdq{HgrxZHP@DBDDFDHDHBLD\I^Id@I`@?@ADELENEJADGJEHE…@^[TIFi@Zw@^aAZiDdAYJaAX}HbC_AXcIdC]JeFzAu@Vm@TQJ"}
4: {duration: 166, polyline: "eyu{H}`zZy@\u@\MDEDUL[Ri@Zg@ZSNc@Z]Xg@b@i@d@e@d@]^…OAOCk@Gk@Ii@M_AUe@Mk@Sq@W_@Qi@Um@[a@SoAu@y@e@eBaA"}
5: {duration: 79, etc.
```

Expected behaviour should be (with some tweaks) that animatedmarker starts at the beginning of the first polyline, then iterate over the next lines so I can destroy the marker when it reaches its last GPS position on each polyline and begin with the next one until the journey is over.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I took the movingMarker function out of the $.each iteration and placed it directly after the Ajax call. Now I can use .flat() to use the nested array of legs as own array and loop through one array of legs, instead of dealing with each given array of legs.

```
        $.ajax(settings2).done(function (response) {
        
        var rep;
        rep = clicked_id;

        //first fetch the leg array from the Ajax call
        var legs = new Array(response.currentTravel.legs)
        var arr = legs.flat()
        //console.log(arr)

        //function promise to wait for given ms to start
        const waitFor = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
        const asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
         for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            await callback(array[index], index, array)
          }
        }
        
        //iterate through each leg using key/value pairs for leg, waitFor & speed values
        const start = async () => {
          await asyncForEach(arr, async (num) => {
            await waitFor(num.waitFor*10)
            var leg = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(num.polyline)
            var myMovingMarker = L.Marker.movingMarker(leg.getLatLngs(), num.duration*10).addTo(map);
            myMovingMarker.start();
            setTimeout(function() {
                myMovingMarker.remove();
            }, num.duration*10);
          })
          //log done when all legs are finished
          console.log('Done')
        }
        //start the await/sync 
        start()

    // this will show all legs as one big route                                 
    $.each(response.currentTravel.legs, function(index) { 

    var polyline = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(response.currentTravel.legs[index].polyline);
    polyline.addTo(map);        
    
});
});
```

Using await/sync based on the duration of the leg and a waitfor addition within the results I've succeeded in plotting all polylines from the array of polylines as one route, and then start a moving marker at the beginning of the route, following specific speeds over the route at some given point, while deleting the marker when another movingmarker starts.

Hope someone ever finds this post, whenever needed. Adios!